# "Bad value ... for attribute name on element meta" errors for meta tags

Tags: html, google-plus, meta-tags, w3c-validation

The [Google+ JS API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) shows credentials and settings can be set using meta tags instead of passing through a JS call. Examples:

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="CLIENT_ID" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
```

I tried this on my website and it works, but when I try to
validate my HTML [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) gives errors such as:

> Bad value google-signin-callback for attribute name on element meta:
>   Keyword google-signin-callback is not registered.
>
> Bad value google-signin-clientid for attribute name on element meta:
>   Keyword google-signin-clientid is not registered.
>
> Bad value google-signin-cookiepolicy for attribute name on element
>   meta: Keyword google-signin-cookiepolicy is not registered.
>
> Bad value google-signin-scope for attribute name on element meta:
>   Keyword google-signin-scope is not registered.

Is the HTML code Google provides as an example really invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are validating against HTML5 (this can be seen from the error messages), and as per HTML5 drafts, only a limited set of `name` attribute values are allowed in a `meta` element. So as an HTML5 document, the document is invalid, since the values used are among those allowed. HTML5 defines a registration procedure, but apparently Google cannot be bothered to use it.

If you validate against XHTML 1.0, the code will pass, because in XHTML 1.0, the `name` attribute value can be any name, like `<meta name="Hi, I’m trying to make a point” content="" />`. The same applies to HTML 4.01, except that the slash before “/” would cause a syntax error in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid HTML, the names being used are not part of the official standard. That's fine though since they are namespaced with `google` so you shouldn't have any issues.